# Update all image paths from http to https in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla-1.5, ssl, https

We have changed our website from **http** to **https**.  The site has more than 2000 articles containing images with paths using `http://`.

We need to replace all images from `http` to `https`. I searched for plugins to do this, but most of the plugins are designed to support Joomla 3+.

I found just one plugin, but it's not working.

How can we fix this issue with the image paths on Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PHP to perform global redirects like this. It needs to be done at server level, rather than application level.

You can achieve this by adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to make an SQL query replacing `src="http://yourwebsitedomain` to `src="https://yourwebsitedomain` of course database backup is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external script to get your database in order. I have used this one from interconnect/it a lot on both Joomla and Wordpress. It is awesome and totally free. It is a script you upload to your server, no plugin needed. It even does a dry run before doing a live run so you can be sure you are only searching and replacing what you need and not grabbing unintended results.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Don't worry about link name, it will work on any database type cms system. It works really well with Joomla.

And I would recommend you just search and replace `http://yourdomainname.com/images` with a relative link such as `/images` or just `images`

Answer (score 0):

Run a backup first and then use Regular Labs DBReplacer to find and replace the relevant links in the database.

The last version of DBReplacer that is compatible with Joomla 1.5 is version 2.2.2:

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/dbreplacer/changelog#v2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReReplacer extension. It can dynamically "Search and Replace" any code on you joomla website. So you can make it search for "http://" and replace it with "https://" or if you want to be more specific you could search "http://mysite.com" and replace with "https://mysite.com" so only it will do it on your domain.

Download the extension from here: https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/rereplacer/changelog#v4.3.0

You need the 4.3.0 version of the extension, because is the latest that supports Joomla 1.5

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  A well-crafted answer.  Please continue to hunt for questions where you can share your knowledge.